# Figuring out what data in EF model was changed during an edit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using EF 6 in code first to make my database and can easily save new and changed data but what I would like to figure out is an easy way to figure out what data was changed when the user edits a page. This is the code I am using in the controller for my edit page:

```
    [Route("Edit"), HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult EditSection([Bind(Include = "ID, RouteName, Type, Title, Synopsis")] Section section, HttpPostedFileBase Logo)
    {
        SectionAddEditVM model = new SectionAddEditVM { Section = section };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(section).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

The only way I could think of is pulling the data from the DB and doing a line by line comparison but that seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Think you should use reflection like in this sample

[Loop Through An Objects Properties In C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957783/loop-through-an-objects-properties-in-c-sharp)

And compare the two objects in the same way :)

The only thing you should change is the result instead of returning a boolean you could return a list of diffObjects ( just a name for a class that describes the differences.)

Comment: As stated in my OP, I was hoping for a simpler way then a line by line comparison.

Comment: That is not possible and Jon Skeet's code is really both nice looking and generic. And when you have implemented earlier mentioned method you can use this on "all" your classes.

Comment: I agree, that is nice clean code to throw in a class to call up. I was just really hoping there was some built in way that was easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can further query the Entry for it's changes. Take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15412646/856595) for an example of how to make EF do the work for you. With LINQ, you can easily consume the changes and compose them for human use, auditing, et al.